# Instantiating a class in my route file gives the following error: Function calls are not supported in decorators

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I am building a complex multi step application form and the flow of the application changes depending on the answers given by the user. I have one class which contains an enum of all my routes and this class is accessible throughout my application in different classes. 
Since this class is the only place that holds all the different path values I instantiate this in my routes file and define my paths like this:

```
    const enums = new MortgageFormEnums();
    export const mortgageFormRoutes = [
    {
     path: 'mortgage',
     component: MortgageComponent,
     children: [
      {
       path: enums.routes.properties[enums.routes.start].url,
       component: StartComponent
      },
      {
       path: enums.routes.properties[enums.routes.whatsUp].url,
       component: WhatsUpComponent
      },
      etc...
    }
    ];
```

When I build my application for prod using AoT, I get the error: 
ERROR in src\app\mortgage\mortgage-form.module.ts(42,27): Error during template compile of 'MortgageFormModule'
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'MortgageFormEnums' was called in 'mortgageFormRoutes'
'mortgageFormRoutes' calls 'MortgageFormEnums'.

Ideally I would like to keep the route paths just in one file as an enum so that I can access it in other parts of the app. Is there any way to achieve this rather than hard coding my paths inside the routes file as well?

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorators don't live in runtime, therefore you cannot run code in the metadata. You could simply export a variable instead of a class and import that.

```
export const sharedStuff = { foo:1 };
```

Comment: thank you that got rid of one problem but has created another, I guess I'll ask in a new post. Cheers

Comment: I don't understand your explanation.  Whe we use RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes),   it works perfectly.
And strangely when I try to copy the way it is coded inside RouterModule.forRoot() it doesn't work.